# Stop current iteration of Quartz.NET Job

Tags: c#, .net, scheduler, quartz.net

I would like to know if it is possible to stop the current iteration of job execution with Quartz.NET.

Here is my need:

A job is scheduled to run every 5 minutes. It sends a request to an external organism, and wait for his answer. If no answer after 5 minutes, it sends the request to another organism.
But the external organism can answer to that request. If it answers in time, I need to trigger the next execution (i.e. send the request to the next organism, and not waiting the remaining time).

I've searched through Quartz.NET documentation but couldn't find any answer. If anyone has a clue on how to implement that kind of thing.

Thanks !

Comment: what kind of request is it?

Comment: it is a request to know whether the organism is available or not

Comment: i mean, is it a `HttpWebRequest` or what?

Comment: From your description, this doesn't sound like something you need to be using Quartz.NET for. It sounds like you need a single process which fires off a request with a timeout of five minutes. Whenever the request ends - either by success or by timeout - you fire off another request. There doesn't seem to be any need for a timer here.

Comment: oh sorry, it is a SignalR notification. The organism answers to the request through REST service

Comment: thus, the timeout on the request is not possible

Comment: OK, but Quartz.NET still seems like odd technology to be using here, unless there's more to it that I'm missing. You can't just create an instance of a System.Timers.Timer when you make each call, and handle your timeout that way?

Comment: Yeah, I think it will be simplier. I thought quartz would be more accurate, but it turns out that it is really much more complicated. Thanks !